# How to get the URL of a file on AWS S3 using aws-sdk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using an AWS Lambda function to create a file and save it to my bucket on S3, it is working fine. After executing the `putObject` method, I get a `data` object, but it only contains an `Etag` of the recently added object.

```
s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    // data only contains Etag
});
```

I need to know the exact URL that I can use in a browser so the client can see the file. The folder has been already made public and I can see the file if I copy the Link from the S3 console.

I tried using `getSignedUrl` but the URL it returns is used for other purposes, I believe.

Thanks!

Comment: a presigned url can be used as a download link, however, it expires after x amount of minutes an works with non-public items.   If your item is public, the easiest thing to do is simply concatenate the URL using the predictable pattern.

Comment: *if I copy the Link from the S3 console*  Do you see the pattern there?  The URL for each object in the bucket follows exactly the same pattern.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The SDKs do not generally contain a convenience method to create a URL for publicly-readable objects. However, when you called PutObject, *you* provided the bucket and the object's key and that's all you need. You can simply combine those to make the URL of the object, for example:

- https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/key

So, for example, if your bucket is `pablo` and the object key is `dogs/toto.png`, use:

- https://pablo.s3.amazonaws.com/dogs/toto.png

Note that S3 keys do not begin with a `/` prefix. A key is of the form `dogs/toto.png`, and not `/dogs/toto.png`.

For region-specific buckets, see [Working with Amazon S3 Buckets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html) and [AWS S3 URL Styles](http://www.wryway.com/blog/aws-s3-url-styles/). Replace `s3` with `s3.<region>.amazonaws.com` or `s3-<region>.amazonaws.com` in the above URLs, for example:

- https://seamus.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dogs/setter.png (with dot)
- https://seamus.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dogs/setter.png (with dash)

If you are using IPv6, then the general URL form will be:

- https://BUCKET.s3.dualstack.REGION.amazonaws.com

For some buckets, you may use the older path-style URLs. Path-style URLs are deprecated and [only work with buckets created on or before September 30, 2020](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/). They are used like this:

- https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/key
- https://s3.amazonaws.com/pablo/dogs/toto.png
- https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/seamus/dogs/setter.png
- https://s3.dualstack.REGION.amazonaws.com/BUCKET

Currently there are TLS and SSL certificate issues that may require some buckets with dots (`.`) in their name to be accessed via path-style URLs. AWS plans to address this. See the [AWS announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/).

**Note:** General guidance on [object keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-keys) where certain characters need special handling. For example space is encoded to + (plus sign) and plus sign is encoded to %2B. Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116450/what-are-valid-s3-key-names-that-can-be-accessed-via-the-s3-rest-api).

Comment: Thanks! I thought the link was prone to change unexpectedly in some naming scenarios.

Comment: Additional post on naming considerations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116450/what-are-valid-s3-key-names-that-can-be-accessed-via-the-s3-rest-api

Comment: That doesn't explain what happens if for instance you use spaces in the name of the file you uploaded. Apparently they get replaced with '+', but maybe there are more rules like this?

Comment: @JorisMans thanks, have added additional references.

Comment: In my case I needed the bucket region too : `http://s3.region.amazonaws.com/bucket/key`. For me region was `eu-west-3`

Comment: It's surprising both how bad the API is, and how bad the documentation is. 5 years later the API still doesn't support this.

Comment: @AndyRay agree that it would be a popular addition to all AWS SDKs so that developers do not have to calculate the URL themselves. You can see an unfulfilled request [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1128), for example.

Answer (score 9):

in case you got the s3bucket and filename objects and want to extract the url, here is an option:

```
function getUrlFromBucket(s3Bucket,fileName){
    const {config :{params,region}} = s3Bucket;
    const regionString = region.includes('us-east-1') ?'':('-' + region)
    return `https://${params.Bucket}.s3${regionString}.amazonaws.com/${fileName}`
};
```

Comment: This doesn't work for non-region-specific buckets. For instance buckets in `us-east-1` don't have the region as part of the url.

Comment: @bPratik , thanks for the comment, i edited the code to support it...

Comment: doesn't properly escape keys either

Comment: what do you mean @jrochkind ?

Comment: I assume @jrochkind means you may want to call `encodeURI` on `fileName` (AKA the key) in case it contains characters that aren't allowed in a URL.

Answer (score 4):

You can do an another call with this:

```
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key'};
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function (err, url) {
  console.log('The URL is', url);
});
```

Comment: Only valid for certain time

Comment: Getting a signed url only makes sense if the s3 file isn't public

Answer (score 2):

I was looking in the documentation and found this [GUIDE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_Scenario_PresignedUrl_section.html) for creating a presigned URL, I ended up realizing that it uses ["@aws-sdk/url-parser"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/url-parser) to transform the url with the key into the pattern from aws.

This was the code I used to get a url:

```
parseUrl(`https://${bucket}.s3.${region}.amazonaws.com/${Key}`)
```

I don't know if it's ideal to do it that way, but I didn't find another solution that was documented by aws

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **Daniel Roy Greenfeld** for writing a detailed [blog](https://daniel.feldroy.com/posts/2022-06-18-s3-getsigned-url-nodejs-aws-sdk-3) for this problem. He took inspiration from [these docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generate-presigned-url-modular-aws-sdk-javascript/). but these docs are hard to find and doesn't provide a copy/pastable solution.

**Install Dependencies**

```
npm i @aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner
npm i @aws-sdk/client-s3
```

**Create Utility Function**

```
import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner";
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
const config = {
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  },
  region: "us-west-2",
};
// Instantiate a new s3 client
const client = new S3Client(config);

async function getSignedFileUrl(fileName, bucket, expiresIn) {
  
  const command = new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: fileName,
  });

  // await the signed URL and return it
  return await getSignedUrl(client, command, { expiresIn });
}

export default getSignedFileUrl;
```

Usage

```
await getFileUrl(thumbnail_key, "my_bucket", 3600);
```