# AWS S3 Cli get object urls

Tags: amazon-web-services, object, url, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I want to list the object URLs of all files in my public bucket. I read all the documents about s3 and s3api, but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

I don't want to define the pre-sign URL. I want to list the existing URLs of all files in the folder.

I'm sorry I couldn't add code, but I have a very specific problem and I can't find my starting point.

I'd appreciate it if someone help.

Solution:
https://github.com/cagdasdemirer/AWS-S3-URL-Listing

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a direct way to get the URLs of all the S3 files in bucket. This is how can do it:

1. List all the files in S3 using:

> aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name/folder-name

2. Build a URL like this:

> http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/key (for path-style URL), or
>
> http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/key (for virtual-hosted style URL)

3. Store it in the folder.

This SO link may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44401684/7541412

Let me know if it helped.

Thanks

Comment: Good advice, just keep in mind if you do down this route, you'll need to encode any special characters you have in your object names, like spaces.

Comment: It helped me approach from a different perspective. Thanks.

Comment: Disappointing that there is no direct support for this.