# Get uploaded object URL with Javascript 'aws-sdk' v3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

Currently, we are using `aws-sdk` v2, and extracting uploaded file URL in this way

```
  const res = await S3Client
    .upload({
      Body: body,
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: key,
      ContentType: contentType,
    })
    .promise();

  return res.Location;
```

Now we have to upgrade to `aws-sdk` v3, and the new way to upload files looks like this

```
const command = new PutObjectCommand({
  Body: body,
  Bucket: bucket,
  Key: key,
  ContentType: contentType,
});

const res = await S3Client.send(command);
```

Unfortunately, `res` object doesn't contain `Location` property now.

`getSignedUrl` SDK function doesn't look suitable because it just generates a URL with an expiration date (probably it can be set to some extra huge duration, but anyway, we still need to have a possibility to analyze the URL path)

Building the URL manually does not look like a good idea and a stable solution to me.

Comment: I'm running into this problem too and unfortunately, I think building the URL manually is the only solution here.

Comment: written a detailed answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77773674/6531685

Answer (score 9):

Answering myself: I don't know whether a better solution exists, but here is how I do it

```
const command = new PutObjectCommand({
  Body: body,
  Bucket: bucket,
  Key: key,
  ContentType: contentType,
});

const [res, region] = await Promise.all([
  s3Client.send(command),
  s3Client.config.region(),
]);

const url = `https://${bucket}.s3.${region}.amazonaws.com/${key}`
```

Comment: Probably a good idea to call `encodeURI` on the `key` as well.

Comment: You mean `https://s3.${region}.amazonaws.com/${bucket}/${key}`?

Comment: It looks like a step back respect to SDK v2. Are they forcing us to make an additional request to get the official object URL?

Comment: @aghidini it depends on whether you want virtual-hosted or path styled URL
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/VirtualHosting.html

Comment: @humkins you are right, I was getting SSL certificate errors using the "new" virtual-hosted styled URL but probably I messed up something else

Answer (score 2):

You can use Upload method from "@aws-sdk/lib-storage" with sample code as below.

```
import { Upload } from "@aws-sdk/lib-storage";
import { S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

const target = { Bucket, Key, Body };
  try {
    const parallelUploads3 = new Upload({
      client: new S3Client({}),
      tags: [...], // optional tags
      queueSize: 4, // optional concurrency configuration
      leavePartsOnError: false, // optional manually handle dropped parts
      params: target,
    });

    parallelUploads3.on("httpUploadProgress", (progress) => {
      console.log(progress);
    });

    await parallelUploads3.done();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

Make sure you return `parallelUploads3.done()` object where you will get location in the return object as below

[S3 Upload Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wpoal.png)

Reference

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70159394/16729176