# Retrieve S3 URL of a file uploaded using Paperclip Rails from Node.js

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have an image uploaded to `S3 bucket` using `paperclip` gem from a rails app.

Is there any way to retrieve the URL of that image from `Node.js` since both the app are using the shared DB?

**EDIT**

To clarify further, `file-name` of the images uploaded to S3 are stored in the `file_name` column of the `table`. In rails app, the instance of `table-model` can return the exact URL using the S3 configs specified in `paperclip.rb`.

For e.g., https://s3-region.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/table/column/000/000/345/thumb/file-name.webp?1655104806

where `345` is the PK of the `table`

Comment: see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44401684/5058682) helps.

Comment: @AmitKumar thanks for this doc, it seems like there're multiple path structure. I've edited my question to provide more clarity.