# Special characters is S3 key name of uploaded file

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

## Background

I'm using `aws-android-sdk` to send files from Android app to S3.
The filename contains specials character such as `=`.

To do that, I use `TransferUtility.upload(...)` as explained in [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-data-storage.html#upload-a-file-to-amazon-s3).

## The problem

When passing a key containing special characters such as `=`, the key is being URL encoded.

For example, the key:

```
year=2018/month=1/versions=1,2/my_file.txt
```

Becomes:

```
year%253D2018/month%253D1/versions%253D1%252C2/my_file.txt
```

## My question

How can I upload an S3 file from my Android application, while using special characters in it's key?

Comment: The fact that they are encoded doesn't mean that are not special chars. if you use those chars in your key that's normal. The solution is not to us chars which need encoding while used in URL

Comment: Agree with Mat . @Michael have a look into [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116450/what-are-valid-s3-key-names-that-can-be-accessed-via-the-s3-rest-api) if you already haven't.

Comment: @ADM i've added a proper answer to this, BTW in your link there is the same thing. Probably this question should be closed as duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are valid S3 key names that can be accessed via the S3 rest API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116450/what-are-valid-s3-key-names-that-can-be-accessed-via-the-s3-rest-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not following the key name convention described in this paragraph called [Object Key Guidelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-key-guidelines) of Amazon S3.

Summary from the link:

> The following character sets are generally safe for use in key names:

```
Alphanumeric characters [0-9a-zA-Z]
Special characters !, -, _, ., *, ', (, and )
```

The following are examples of valid object key names:

```
4my-organization
my.great_photos-2014/jan/myvacation.jpg
videos/2014/birthday/video1.wmv
```

Remove those special chars from the URL following the guideline and the problem will disappear

Answer (score 2):

If you are partitioning your data on S3, it's a common practice to use = sign in the S3 key. Also interesting to note that the AWS SDK for iOS does not automatically encode the S3 keys.