# S3 is encoding urls with spaces and symbols to unkown format

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, url, amazon-s3, uri

I have a S3 bucket with static website hosting

S3 is encoding route

```
/AniketFuryRocks/What is Lorem Ipsum?
```

to route

```
/AniketFuryRocks/What+is+Lorem+Ipsum%3F
```

instead of route

```
/AniketFuryRocks/What%20is%20Lorem%20Ipsum?
```

This Url encoding is resulting in a 404 error.

I have tried storing the object's route in both encoded and decoded fashing.

When storing the S3 Object using `javascript encodeUri()` function. Paths with spaces are working but paths with symbols like `?` are not working.

I am noticing that the browser asks for a `?` while s3 expects a `%3F` at the end of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you need to encode symbols in the URL

I made [S3Encode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3encode), npm repository for the same

Here is a function which does the job

```js
function encode(filename) {
    const encodings = {
        '\+': "%2B",
        '\!': "%21",
        '\"': "%22",
        '\#': "%23",
        '\$': "%24",
        '\&': "%26",
        '\'': "%27",
        '\(': "%28",
        '\)': "%29",
        '\*': "%2A",
        '\,': "%2C",
        '\:': "%3A",
        '\;': "%3B",
        '\=': "%3D",
        '\?': "%3F",
        '\@': "%40",
    };

    return filename.replace(
        /([+!"#$&'()*+,:;=?@])/img,
        match => encodings[match]
    );
}
```

Use this function in `anchor` tags and related

eg

```html
<a href=encode("/AniketFuryRocks/What is Lorem Ipsum?")></a>
```

Comment: I have actually removed ":" from the encoding check because it is messed with "https:" then this worked for me.

Comment: could you use `encodeUriComponent` on the individual components of the path and then join them together with "/"? That seems to be working for me