# URL-encoded format for s3 event notification

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform, urlencode

I wanted to use `"projectfolder:/dev/"` as a prefix for my event notification. There's a semicolon in my folder/object's name. However, as mentioned here, I cannot use a colon inside a prefix easily. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-configure-s3-event-notification/

```
module "test" {
  config = module.config
  bucket_name = module.s3_terraform.name
  # s3_prefix = "projectfolder:/dev/"
}
```

I am entering this prefix in terraform. What's the correct way to format the colon string such that it's url encoded?

I tried using this online tool:

and it gave me this:

```
  s3_prefix = "projectfolder%3A%2Fdev"
```

However, this does not manager to run the trigger from S3. When I open the s3 console, under filters, I see the prefix like this: `"projectfolder%3A%2Fdev"` and instead of `"projectfolder:/dev"`

Comment: Isn't `testbucket` the bucket name? The `s3_prefix` setting is specifically a path to tell S3 what objects inside the bucket you want it to send notifications for. You wouldn't include the bucket name in that setting, and you also wouldn't include a colon unless you are also including colons in your object names in the bucket. The `s3_prefix` setting is not a free-form text field fir you to put in whatever format you want.

Comment: So does that prefix/folder (with the colon in the name) currently exist already in your S3 bucket?

Comment: yes it exists @MarkB

Answer (score 0):

Terraform has a [urlencode](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/urlencode) function. So just change it to:

```
s3_prefix = urlencode("projectfolder:/dev/")
```

Comment: I get this on the console under filters ```projectfolder%3A%2Fdev%2F```. However, the trigger still doesn't work. Is this the format I am supposed to see in the UI or should it be displayed as ```"projectfolder:/dev/``` ?